# How can I modify design of bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to front-end. I want to modify design of bootstrap dropdown button like this:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqAvj.png)

Bootstrap dropdown code:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I modify it according to above picture?

Comment: You can create a new class into your css file (.myButton) for example and add it to your button class="". After that you can change colors, borders, ...

Comment: you need to override bootstrap css, write your own css  for the same classes

Comment: Could you prepare some examples if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

see my code below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27337/) for working demo

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  color: red;
      padding: 3px 10px;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a .fa{
      margin-right: 5px;
}

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways..

1. Create a new CSS class with your own style and then add the class to your default jquery dropdown
2. Overide jquery class

Ex for number 1:
Create new CSS class:

```
 .newDropdown {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: #fff
        border: 1px solid #000
    }
```

then add .newDropdown to your html

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu newDropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Ex for number 2:

Just overide the class:

```
.dropdown-menu {
   background-color: #777;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
   padding: 10px
}
```

Or you can read this answer for reference (even they're using select): [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am testing your first example but there is something I cannot solve. When I click the button, it still shows the default bootstrap button css. Can you check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27339/

Comment: I cannot see the updated version of my jsfiddle link

Comment: My question is that when I click the button(?), background color of the button(?) becomes gray while clicking. Default one is blue but while clicking, it becomes gray. I need to also make it blue while clicking. As you see in the link, I edited `question:hover, .question:visited, .question:active, .question:link`, but it still becomes gray while clicking.

Comment: use this `.question:hover, .question:focus, .open .dropdown-toggle.question {
  background-color: blue
}` look a this: https://jsfiddle.net/a9eyhbv9/